# Two implementations of a module with a same name-import problems

Tags: python, import, package, caffe

I use two libraries built on top of caffe: crf-rnn(https://github.com/torrvision/crfasrnn/tree/master/python-scripts) and hed(https://github.com/s9xie/hed/blob/master/examples/hed/), the former for semantic image segmentation, the latter for contour detection. Finally, I realized how to get them to work together for object tracking, but now I face an embarrassing problem: as both are built on top of caffe, they import the same package, but each with very different content, i.e. crf-rnn uses caffe.Segmenter which hed doesn't have and ed uses caffe.TEST which crf-rnn doesn't have.

Python doesn't allow import of two packages with the same name. I've tried finding a workaround by puting hed in a separate Python file and importing it in the main script, and using `as` to `import caffe as cf` for one of the packages, but so far nothing has worked out.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: this is a file called `Aux.py`

```
def import_hed_caffe():
    import sys,os
    caffe_dir = '/home/alex/Downloads/hed/python'
    sys.path.insert(0,caffe_dir)
    hed_model = 'deploy.prototxt'
    hed_pretrained = 'hed_pretrained_bsds.caffemodel'
    import caffe as cf
    net = cf.Net(hed_model, hed_pretrained, cf.TEST)
    return  net
```

This is the main script:

```
caffe_root = '../caffe-crfrnn/'
sys.path.insert(0, caffe_root + 'python')
import caffe as espresso
import AuxScript
net = espresso.Segmenter(MODEL_FILE, PRETRAINED, gpu=False)
a=AuxScript.import_hed_caffe()
```

and I get

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TEST'
```

Needless to say, separately everything works fine, so it's just the import

EDIT 2:

./CMakeFiles

./CMakeFiles/pycaffe.dir

./CMakeFiles/pycaffe.dir/caffe

./caffe

./caffe/imagenet

./caffe/proto

./caffe/test

EDIT 3:

```
├── caffe
│   ├── _caffe.cpp
│   ├── _caffe.so -> /home/alex/Downloads/hed/lib/_caffe.so
│   ├── classifier.py
│   ├── classifier.pyc
│   ├── detector.py
│   ├── detector.pyc
│   ├── draw.py
│   ├── imagenet
│   │   └── ilsvrc_2012_mean.npy
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── io.py
│   ├── io.pyc
│   ├── net_spec.py
│   ├── net_spec.pyc
│   ├── proto
│   │   ├── caffe_pb2.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── pycaffe.py
│   ├── pycaffe.pyc
│   └── test
│       ├── test_layer_type_list.py
│       ├── test_net.py
│       ├── test_net_spec.py
│       ├── test_python_layer.py
│       ├── test_python_layer_with_param_str.py
│       └── test_solver.py
├── classify.py
├── CMakeFiles
│   ├── CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake
│   ├── progress.marks
│   └── pycaffe.dir
│       ├── build.make
│       ├── caffe
│       │   └── _caffe.cpp.o
│       ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│       ├── CXX.includecache
│       ├── DependInfo.cmake
│       ├── depend.internal
│       ├── depend.make
│       ├── flags.make
│       ├── link.txt
│       └── progress.make
├── cmake_install.cmake
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── detect.py
├── draw_net.py
├── Makefile
├── requirements.txt
```

Comment: you mean you tried to rename one of the caffe packages and it didn't work?

Comment: yeah even if i change the path in pythonpath, and reimport caffe, the package I get is still the one with the path to the previous package

Comment: e.g. if I import for crf-rnn and then for hed, this is what happens

Comment: changing the path won't cut it, but renaming should work. Could you post code snippets? And describe both `caffe` file trees?

Comment: In addition of inserting the paths, you have to RENAME one of the `caffe.py` file. Once it is imported, importing another module with the same name won't do anything.

Comment: OK I've added the full tree of the hed/python directory. I'm not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen your last edit, and I must say that changing/tampering with python `sys.path` is necessary in your context but not sufficient here: you have to rename one of the `caffe` packages.

Ex: if the `caffe` package is a directory called `caffe` containing a `__init__.py` file, rename `caffe` to `espresso` and in your code simply:

```
import espresso
```

(if it's just a `caffe.py` file, rename to `espresso.py` although it may be more problematic if there are other modules in the same directory, well worth a try)

BTW: When importing a module, say, `xxx`, you can know which full filepath it is using by typing:

```
print(xxx.__file__)
```

(useful when you have a doubt)

Comment: You agree that it's not possible that you create a file `caffe_1.py` which is in the pythonpath and that you get that error right (except if you forgot the underscore) ? Can you describe your directory structure?

Comment: I added a directory structure. I'm quite suprised this is not a very widely known issue given the number of builds on top of caffe

Comment: I see, those are directory names. So you could rename the `caffe` directory to `espresso` and you will be able to import espresso AND caffe in the same context. Consider them as different products.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I found the least sophisticated solution possible: I wrote two scripts, one for crf-rnn producing the blobs that I ran on the full dataset just once and stored the output.

Then I wrote the second script, with hed edge detector that I use every time I detect and track objects.